# Oracle, dynamically determine column name

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Suppose I have a table of custom column names that all have the pattern COL##, where ## is any integer.  So a typical query would be:

```
select COL12 from MyCustomTable;
```

So in another table, I have all those integers and I'd like to create a query using the table of integers to construct a dynamic query into MyCustomTable.

Something like:

```
select 'COL' || (select colId from IdTable where Id = 12) from MyCustomTable;
```

But instead of just returning the string 'COL12' for every row, return the actual values identified by the column name COL12.

Don't worry about my overall problem :)  I'm just curious to know if I can do this from a sqldeveloper window directly without writing any code/procedures/functions, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obvious and absolutely insecure way of doing this would be usage of [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm) statement.

Another is to use [`SPOOL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm) command to output results into temporary file, then set `SPOOL OFF` and execute this file with [`@`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/script.php) directive.

Comment: I saw the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in some other searches I did, but was hoping for something else.  Hadn't considered the SPOOL option.  Accepting, since I believe these both to be good answers.